# Getting error in requesting access token with graph.facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-access-token

I'm testing OAuth 2.0 with facebook API, after receiving the authorization code and requesting the access token with the GET `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/oauth/access_token?` i got this response :

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "Dl3lYjJLKKy"
}
```

}

the redirect_uri is the same as the one in the login dialog since i'm just testing on localhost.

Everything was working fine till today,i even tested new callback url using localtunnel but it didn't work at all

Comment: _“since i'm just testing on localhost”_ - what does that have to do with anything? `http://localhost/foo` and `http://localhost/bar` are still two different URLs, even though you are just testing on localhost. This has no bearing on the issue _at all_.

Comment: i'm using http:// localhost / as callback, that's what i meant,but still have the issue...

Comment: You need to pass the _exact same_ value for the `redirect_uri` parameter in this API call, as you did in your redirect to the login dialog.

Comment: i'm using on both the redirect_uri http: // localhost ,but it gives me the error i attached before.

Comment: So what is the full URL in the browser address bar the moment the login dialog gets shown?

Comment: https:// www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=614976532331146&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080

note:i'm now using port 8080 on both the redirect_uri.

Comment: And what exactly does your API call look like? Did you use :8080 before already, or did the problem only arise when you changed it to that from the “default” port?

Comment: problem stayed even before i changed to port 8080, i was using default 80